# TypeScript - Function return type based on multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, type-parameter

I'm creating a function that exports an image. It needs to take the `format`, `exportType` and `pathOrWithMetadata` parameters. I have the following code:

```
interface ExportMetadata {
    data: Buffer;
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

export type Format = "png" | "jpeg";

export type ExportTypes = "file" | "buffer";

export type Output<ExportType> = ExportType extends "file" ? undefined : Buffer;

export default async function exportTo<ExportType extends ExportTypes>(
    image: Image,
    format: Format,
    exportType: ExportType,
    pathOrWithMetadata?: string | boolean
): Promise<Output<ExportType>> { ... }
```

This will ensure that if the `exportType` is `"file"`, `undefined` will be returned. But if the `exportType` is `"Buffer"`, a `Buffer` will be returned. Now, I need the `Buffer` return type to be dependent on the `pathOrWithMetadata` parameter. Firstly, if the `exportType` is `"file"`, `pathOrWithMetadata` must be a string. If the `exportType` is `"buffer"`, it needs to be a boolean. If the boolean is `true`, the return type needs to be `ExportMetadata`. If it's `false` **or `undefined`**, it needs to return a `Buffer`.

Here's what I tried:

```
interface ExportMetadata {
    data: Buffer;
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

export type Format = "png" | "jpeg";

export type ExportTypes = "file" | "buffer";

export type PathOrWithMetadataOptions = string | boolean;

export type Output<ExportType, PathOrWithMetadata> = ExportType extends "file" ? undefined : (PathOrWithMetadata extends true ? ExportMetadata : Buffer);

export default async function exportTo<ExportType extends ExportTypes, PathOrWithMetadata extends PathOrWithMetadataOptions>(
    image: Image,
    format: Format,
    exportType: ExportType,
    pathOrWithMetadata?: PathOrWithMetadata
): Promise<Output<ExportType, PathOrWithMetadata>> { ... }
```

This worked for the following use cases:

```
exportTo(image, "png", "file", "example.png"); // Promise<undefined>
exportTo(image, "png", "buffer", true); // Promise<ExportMetadata>
exportTo(image, "png", "buffer", false); // Promise<Buffer>
```

But didn't work when `pathOrWithMetadata` is `undefined`:

```
exportTo(image, "png", "buffer");
```

The return type here is `Promise<ExportMetadata | Buffer>`. How can I have the return type be `Promise<Buffer>`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to be to set a default value for the `PathOrWithMetadata` like so:

```
export default async function exportTo<ExportType extends ExportTypes, PathOrWithMetadata extends PathOrWithMetadataOptions = false>(...): Promise<Output<ExportType, PathOrWithMetadata>> { ... }
```